# How to Send Hotkeys via SSH to OMXPlayer with JSch?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, omxplayer

I want to be able to play a video on my Raspberry Pi and control it from my phone.  After looking into this I decided to use a SSH connection and then play a video from a link using OMXPlayer.  At first I used a `session.openChannel("exec");` channel to send the command which would look like `omxplayer '[link]'`  However, after looking around I found that the `exec` channel can only really execute a single command or a chain of commands as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352764/multiple-commands-using-jsch), this is not suitable as I need to be able to pause at any time.  So instead I used the `shell` channel. As a test I just used the default Input and Output streams.

Note: I'm using JSch for the SSH

```
try {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session sesh = jsch.getSession("pi", "***.***.***.***", 22);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sesh.setConfig(config);
        sesh.setPassword("*");
        sesh.connect(3000);
        Channel chan = sesh.openChannel("shell");

        chan.setInputStream(System.in);
        chan.setOutputStream(System.out);
        chan.connect(3000);
    } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code opens up a semi functioning shell which I can use to execute the command, and the video plays however, the hot keys (space = play/pause, q = exit, left arrow = seek back, right arrow = seek forward) do not work I have tried just pressing the key as you would in a normal shell and pressing the key and enter just as a test but neither worked.  So the question is does anyone know how to get the hot keys working in the shell channel?  Or does anyone know how to get the hotkeys working with the exec channel the way I need it to with JSCH?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, you should actually use the "exec" channel, as you are executing a single command only, the `omxplayer`. You do not need a "shell" for it.

Comment: And make sure you understand that you are losing protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), by using `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok I didn't know if the subsequent actions counted as commands or not

Comment: For OpenSSH server, the command is only what you would enter on shell prompt.

Comment: If my other answer helped you, please consider upvoting it.