# Search file on SSH server for a pattern (with less command) using JSch

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh, jsch

I am currently trying to access a Linux server and run some commands.
The general idea is to search for a log file containing certain text and then access that log, search for the requisite text and store all the data currently displayed on the screen in a String.

This approach works fine through PuTTY but now the requirement is different.

I have accomplished this task on other commands like `ls` and other commands that provide a direct output. However, I am having no luck with commands like `less` or `more`.

I have of course tried on sending the entire contents of the log to an array list and then searching for my text (seeing as I will have a relative idea of the position of the data once the 1st line is found). However, this takes a huge amount of time as the log size varies from 10 Mb to 750 Mb.

I would appreciate if anyone can think of another approach or provide any ideas towards a feasible way to this approach.

For reference:
Code I have tried

```
public class check {

private Session session;

private String username = "user";
private String password = "pass";
private String hostname = "host";

public SSHConnectionManager() 
{ }

public SSHConnectionManager(String hostname, String username, String password) 
{
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public void open() throws JSchException 
{
    open(this.hostname, this.username, this.password);
}

public void open(String hostname, String username, String password) throws JSchException
{

    JSch jSch = new JSch();

    session = jSch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
    Properties config = new Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  // not recommended
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword(password);

    System.out.println("Connecting SSH to " + hostname + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected!");
}

public String runCommand(String command) throws JSchException, IOException 
{

    String ret = "";

    if (!session.isConnected())
        throw new RuntimeException("Not connected to an open session.  Call open() first!");

    ChannelExec channel = null;
    channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

    channel.setCommand(command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream(); // channel.getInputStream();

    channel.connect();

    ret = getChannelOutput(channel, in);

    channel.disconnect();

    System.out.println("Finished sending commands!");

    return ret;
}


private String getChannelOutput(Channel channel, InputStream in) throws IOException
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String line = "";
    while (true){
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, i));
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        if(line.contains("logout")){
            break;
        }

        if (channel.isClosed()){
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee){}
    }

    return strBuilder.toString();   
}

public void close()
{        
    session.disconnect();
    System.out.println("Disconnected channel and session");
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SSHConnectionManager ssh = new SSHConnectionManager();
    try {
        ssh.open();
        String ret = ssh.runCommand("ls -l");
        System.out.println(ret);
        ret=ssh.runCommand("cd *move to path of log*");
        System.out.println(ret);
        ret=ssh.runCommand("less *log name*");
        System.out.println(ret);
        ret=ssh.runCommand("/*searchtext*");
        System.out.println(ret);


        ssh.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the necesaary output for my ls command but not for any of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code executes every command in its own separate shell. So the `cd` command has no effect on the `less` command. Send, `/*searchtext*` is not a command at all. Note that `setCommand` is not an equivalent of typing something in SSH console window. It's completely different interface.

First step would be to execute all commands in the same shell. For that use a shell technique of your server. On Linux server, you would use semicolon or double ampersand. As for example shown here: [Multiple commands using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17352764/850848).

Though it won't help you with the `/*searchtext*`. You should not try to use "human" techniques for automation.

In the end, the better solution is to actually do everything with a single command, like using `grep`:

```
grep *searchtext* *move to path of log*/*log name*
```